# Symfony form is valid even on invalid data

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I have a strange problem.

My form is valid by symfony even if the provided data are not. This form is created and posted by ajax requests (it this can affect it)

```
    if(!$request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
        return new JsonResponse(['code' => 403], 403);
    }

    $name = $request->query->get('name');

    $contact = new Contact();
    $contact->setName($name);

    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(ContactType::class, $contact);

    if($request->isMethod('POST')){
        $form->submit($request);
        if($form->isValid()){
            $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');

            $em->persist($contact);
            $em->flush();

            return new JsonResponse(['code' => 200, 'id' => $contact->getId(), 'name' => $contact->getName()]);
        }

        return new JsonResponse(['formView' => $this->renderView('@MyBundle/Contacts/contactForm.html.twig',['form' =>$form->createView()]), 'code' => 400, 'errors' => $form->getErrors(true)]);
    }

    return new JsonResponse(['formView' => $this->renderView('@MyBundle/Contacts/contactForm.html.twig',['form' =>$form->createView()]), 'code' => 200], 200);
```

With data looking like this (retvrieved with xdebug):

```
   'id' => NULL,
   'name' => NULL,
   'companyId' => NULL,
   'companyTaxId' => NULL,
   'birthNumber' => NULL,
   'phoneLandLine' => NULL,
   'phoneMobile' => NULL,
   'phoneFax' => NULL,
   'email' => NULL,
   'www' => NULL,
```

Problem is, that name, which is set as required, is null, even though form is marked as valid and there are no errors. After this, there is a doctrine exception about missing required field.

Do you have any clue why this should happen?

Symfony v2.8.10, Doctrine v1.6.4

Comment: Is the name is set as not nullable in the entity?

Comment: Please, use `handleRequest` instead `submit` and `isSumitted` instead `isMethod` see example best practices here http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/forms.html#handling-form-submits and check later your Constraints inside `Contact` class.

Comment: Yes, it is set as not null (or default doctrine behavior on non referenced variable). But I always thought that my definition of form fields is what says if it is or not required.

I've tried handleRequest and isSubmitted, but that is only different approach how to get data from submited form. Validation itself has not worked for both ways.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, validation is not enabled for "name" field.
To enable it - add NotBlank annotation to your entity:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 *     
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $name;
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/NotBlank.html

Or add constraint directly to the form:

```
$builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class, [
            'constraints' => [
                new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank(),
            ],
        ])
```

Comment: Thanks! I was unable to set a required field with the common way (`"required" =>  true`) on my REST API (`$form->isValid()` didn't catch missing fields). Instead of this, `new NotBlank()` is working perfectly and i'm now able to catch missing fields :)

Answer (score 0):

The **required** attribute does not act as a validator.
Quoting from http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/types/text.html#required

> If true, an HTML5 required attribute will be rendered. The corresponding label will also render with a required class.
>
> This is superficial and independent from validation. At best, if you let Symfony guess your field type, then the value of this option will be guessed from your validation information.

Take a look at http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/forms.html#form-validation

Comment: I've added Assert constraints to the entity, but it didn't help. I will try this possible solution and then perhaps start looking deeply in symfony, why validation is not working.